# IDL compare 1000 tifs from Meteosat and create a new one

Tags: tiff, idl-programming-language, envi

I need to compare the bands 2,3,6 and 9 of the Meteosat-8 all 15min. I already did the calculation for the brightness temperature and I managed to read all Tifs into IDL.

Now i did some Ratios. Like B6-B4, B9-3... Now I want to create a new Tif, where it writes (and later add up) a 1 or a 0 in it when some conditions are reached.

The result should be a Tif, where I have the amount of the "1" in every pixel.
I think I have to create a new array with the cols/rows and write after every "for loop" the 1 and 0 in it and add it up every time.

Thanks!
bumi

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Sry. I try again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it to read tiffs and compare them in a new tif.
I did a for loop to load all paths in.

The program works until there is a missing file (path doesn't exist). So I want to skip (continue) all the missing "paths".

I think, I can do it with file_info or file_test.

x=file_info(filepath(path), exists)
if x eq 0 then continue

exists: True(1) if the file exists. False (0) if it does not exists.

thanks